# ViewModel not Working?

Tags: android

I am following exactly the same as mentioned in the official documentation.

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;
    public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
        if (users == null) {
            users = new MutableLiveData<List<Users>>();
            loadUsers(); //the method is working fine
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

And then in activity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a ViewModel the first time the system calls an activity's onCreate() method.
        // Re-created activities receive the same MyViewModel instance created by the first activity.

        MyViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        model.getUsers().observe(this, users -> {
            // update UI
        });
    }
}
```

My load users method is working fine. But IDE is giving an error that lambda expressions are not supported. I also updated the JDK but still it is not working.

Comment: I think you should edit the title so it reflects your question, it's not the `ViewModel` it's the Lambda expressions

Comment: Its not mandatory to use lambda. Try adding `compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }` in build.gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating `JDK` will surely work I think. But even if it is not working then it is not necessary to use `Lambda` Expression.

Convert your code to the old way like this.

```
model.getUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<User> userList) {
                //do whatever you want with the list
            }
        });
```

Try this way I am sure it will work.

Source: [Android ViewModel Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-viewmodel-using-retrofit/)

Comment: Ok let me tray. Thanks anyway